# How do I get the HTTP response status code in AngularJS 1.2

Tags: angularjs, httpresponse, response-headers

Using `ngResource` in AngularJS 1.2rc(x), how do I get the status code now?

```
RestAPI.save({resource}, {data}, function( response, responseHeaders ) {
});
```

where `RestAPI` is my `ngResource`.

The response has the `$promise` object and the resource returned from the server but not a status anymore. The `responseHeaders()` function only has a status if the server injects the status code into the header object, but not the true returned status code. So some servers may serve it and some might not.

Comment: Looks like similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417533/angularjs-with-ngresource-how-to-check-exact-response-from-server

Comment: not similar at all. Its similar in the sense that both questions are asking about AngularJS and using ngResource but other than that completely different. I can get the response data just fine through response. What I can't get is the HTTP response status code in 1.2rc(x), which is a breaking change.

Comment: refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/41179647/2851184

Answer (score 13):

You can use the promiss callbacks `then`, `catch` and `finally` after the `$resource` call.

For example. If you want to catch an error after a call, you would do something like this:

```
RestAPI.save({resource}, {data}, callbackFunction).$promise.catch(function(response) {
    //this will be fired upon error
    if(response.status == 500) alert('Something baaad happend');
}).then(function() {
    //this will be fired upon success
});
```

The `response` object will have `status` and the `statusText` properties. `status` being an integer status code and `statusText` the text. You'll also have the `data` property containing the server response.

edit: as suggested, it was `response.status`

Comment: I return a 400 from my WebAPI and that still doesn't trigger the catch.  The "then" doesn't have response in it.

Comment: Not true my responses do not have the status

Answer (score 12):

You must add an interceptor inside your resource declaration. Like this:

```
var resource = $resource(url, {}, {
    get: {
        method: 'GET'
        interceptor: {
            response: function(response) {      
                var result = response.resource;        
                result.$status = response.status;
                return result;
            }
        }
    }                            
});
```

Usage:

```
resource.get(params, function(result) {
    console.log(result.$status)
});
```

IMO status code should have been provided by default.
There is an issue for this https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8341

Comment: This does not work if connection is not successful. If you have a 404 error it will not show it.

Comment: @MarioShtika this is an old answer. Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/24791928/1324935 ?

Comment: @MarioShtika as far as I can remember there was an error callback as well. In your case the 404 error should be handled in there. It was a long time ago and I don't program with angular anymore.

Comment: I believe that the answer is a combination of both, because in the Bardiels's answer it doesn't show the status when the connection is successfull

Comment: @MarioShtika  yeah probably

Answer (score 4):

For anyone using a newer version of Angular, looks like we've had access to the status code as a 3rd param to the `transformResponse` function [since angular 1.3](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/1b740974f5eb373bed04071d51f908ced7c5a8e5), but it was never documented properly in the [$resource](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/docs/api/ngResource/service/$resource) docs.

Answer (score 3):

I agreed `responseHeaders()` function will only return response's header,but you can custom  it and it's useful anyway.

### 1.

To solve you problem. With the following:(`$$service` is my $resource instance.)

```
var serve = new $$service();
serve.id = "hello_wrongPath"; // wrong path,will return 404
serve.$get()
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log("~~~hi~~~");
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("~~~error~~~");
        console.log(error);
        console.log(error.status); // --> 404
        console.log(error.statusText); // --> "Not Found"
        console.log(error.config.timeout); // --> 5000
        console.log(error.config.method); // --> GET
        console.log(error.config.url); // --> request url
        console.log(error.headers("content-type"));// --> "text/plain"
        return error.$promise;
    })
    .finally(function(data){
        console.log("~~~finally~~~");
        console.log(data); // --> undefined
    });
```

In this way,u can only catch `status,statusText,timeout,method,headers(same with responseHeaders)` in ERROR response.

### 2.

If you want to see response details in success response,I used a interceptor like this:

```
ng.module("baseInterceptor", [])
    .factory("baseInterceptor", ["$q", function ($q) {
        return {
            'request': function (config) {
                console.info(config);
                //set timeout for all request
                config.timeout = 5000;
                return config;
            },
            'requestError': function (rejection) {
                console.info(rejection);
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            },
            'response': function (response) {
                console.log("~~interceptor response success~~");
                console.log(response);
                console.log(response.status);
                console.log(response.config.url);
                return response;
            },
            'responseError': function (rejection) {
                console.log("~~interceptor response error~~");
                console.log(rejection);
                console.log(rejection.status);
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    }]);
```

and then add interceptor to module:

```
.config(["$httpProvider", function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push("baseInterceptor");
}])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get response status like this:

```js
$http.get(url).then(function(response){
  console.log(response.status); //successful status like OK
}, function(response){
  console.log(response.status); //error status like 400-Bad Request
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the right answer is a combination of Bardiel's and Ara's answers.

After adding an interceptor inside your resource declaration. Like this:

```
var resource = $resource(url, {}, {
    get: {
        method: 'GET'
        interceptor: {
            response: function(response) {      
                var result = response.resource;        
                result.$status = response.status;
                return result;
            }
        }
    }                            
});
```

Use it as below:

```
RestAPI.save()
.query(function(response) {
    // This will return status code from API like 200, 201 etc
    console.log(response.$status);
})
.$promise.catch(function(response) {
    // This will return status code from server side like 404, 500 etc
    console.log(response.status);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using AngularJS v1.5.6, and I do it like this (in my case I put the "getData" method inside a service):

```
function getData(url) {
    return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
        $http.get(url).then(success, error);

        function success(response) {
            resolve(response);
        }
        function error(err) {
            reject(err);
        }
    });
}
```

then in the controller (for example), call that like this:

```
function sendGetRequest() {
    var promise = service.getData("someUrlGetService");
    promise.then(function(response) {
        //do something with the response data
        console.log(response.data);
    }, function(response) {
        //do something with the error
        console.log('Error status: ' + response.status);
    });
}
```

As documentation says, the response object has these properties:

> - data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
> - status – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
> - headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
> - config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
> - statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

I had faced the similar problem.I looked into the angular lib and added a few lines to have status returned in the response itself.In this file,find where promise is being returned.

Replace code block starting with

> var promise = $http(httpConfig).then(function(response)

with the following

```
var promise = $http(httpConfig).then(function(response) {
            var data = response.data,
                promise = value.$promise;

            if (data) {
              // Need to convert action.isArray to boolean in case it is undefined
              // jshint -W018
              if ( angular.isArray(data) !== (!!action.isArray) ) {
                throw $resourceMinErr('badcfg', 'Error in resource configuration. Expected ' +
                  'response to contain an {0} but got an {1}',
                  action.isArray?'array':'object', angular.isArray(data)?'array':'object');
              }
              // jshint +W018
              if (action.isArray) {
                value.length = 0;
                forEach(data, function(item) {
                  value.push(new Resource(item));
                });
              } else {
                copy(data, value);
                value.$promise = promise;
              }
            }

            value.status = response.status;
            value.$resolved = true;

            response.resource = value;

            return response;
          }, function(response) {
            value.status = response.status;
            value.$resolved = true;

            (error||noop)(response);

            return $q.reject(response);
          });
```

or you can add this line

```
value.status = response.status;
```

and then access status in code like reponse.status.Though,this is kind of hack but worked for me.I also had to make changes in the minified version.