# How can I get status code using $resource?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

My factory for making request is here:

```
angular.module('myapp').factory('testResponse',
        ['$http', '$resource', 'AppConfig', '$routeParams', '$rootScope',
            function($http, $resource, $routeParams, $rootScope) {
                $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = authorizationHeader;
                $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
                return $resource('test.json'), {}, {
                    query: {method: 'GET'}
                };
            }]);
```

The code in controller is here:

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('TestCtrl',
        ['$http', '$scope', 'testResponse', 'AppConfig', function TestCtrl($http, $scope, testResponse) {
                testResponse.query(function(data) {
                    console.log(data.status);
                })
            }]);
```

Ideally it should log the status as in $http request but I am unable to get it for $reource

Comment: The point is you don't need the status when dealing with successful requests for resources. And as for logging: An interceptor seems to be the more appropriate tool for that. But you are right: the status is not available.

Comment: What can be done to check cases like 404, 500 or 403 etc

Comment: Those are failure cases. You deal with them in the failure handler and there you have access to the status. Your example only uses a success handler.

Comment: Thanks @zeroflagL ! I tried [This snippet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20584367/how-to-handle-resource-service-errors-in-angularjs), but I am still not able to handle failure cases. it caused another error "undefined" ie $promise is not a function and when i injected it, I got Unknown provider $promiseprovider<$promise

Comment: Another example of why `$resource` should not be used... accessing the status code on success is not an unusual scenario... this data should be made available by default, not hidden from you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried use promises with $q to handle this kind of scenario where I had to have more control on failure or success.
I refactored the factory like here:

```
var defObj = $q.defer();
  var testResponse = $resource('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', {}, {
    query: {
      method: 'GET'
    }
  });
  testResponse.query().$promise.then(function(data) {
    //you can add anything else you want inside this function
    defObj.resolve(data);
    console.log(defObj, data);
  }, function(error) {
    //you can add anything else you want inside this function
    console.error("Service failure: " + error);
  });
  return defObj.promise;
}
```

Here is the complete solution in [this pen](http://codepen.io/samdeesh/pen/WorzKb?editors=1010)  (uses mock json to simulate the response)

Comment: I could not get the exact server status codes but this workaround allowed me to look for errors and get more control

Comment: refer to my answer below to get the exact server status code.

Answer (score 6):

In service `testResponse` you can change your return statement to this

```
return $resource('test.json'), {}, {
    query: {
        method: 'GET',
        transformResponse: function(data, headers,statusCode) {
            console.log(statusCode);//prints 200 if nothing went wrong
            var finalRsponse = {
                data: data,
                responseStatusCode: statusCode
            };
        return finalRsponse;
    }}
};
```

And in your controller's success method of then(success,error) of testResponse service you can access the status code using `data.responseStatusCode`.

I have tested it on `angularjs-1.2.32` and `1.5.7`.

Answer (score 0):

```
['$http', '$resource', 'AppConfig', '$routeParams', '$rootScope',
        function($http, $resource, $routeParams, $rootScope) {
```

You have missed `AppConfig` parameter.