# Error status codes are not being caught

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, ionic-v1

I am trying to catch angular resource's HTTP error status code (!=200).
My Service, where I have resources defined:
(apiService.js)

```
.factory('ApiService', function($resource, $http, localStorageService, CONFIG) {

    var base_api_url = api_url = CONFIG.api_url, api_version_prefix = CONFIG.api_version_prefix;

    return {
        userDevices: $resource(api_url+'/requestRegistration/userDevices/:action', {}, {
            registerDevice: {
                method: 'POST',
                params: {
                   action: ''
                }
            },
            verify: {
                method: 'POST',
                params: {
                   action: 'verify'
                }
            },               
        }
    }
});
```

My controller's code:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function(CONFIG, $scope, $state, $ionicPlatform, $ionicPopup, ApiService) {


    $scope.data = {
        username: null
    };

    $scope.registerDevice = function() {
        if($scope.data.username) { 
            var authenticationResponse = ApiService.userDevices.registerDevice({
                username: $scope.data.username
            });

            authenticationResponse.$promise.then(function(result) {
                // this is always fired, even then response code is 400 or 503 :( I am not able to check response status code.
                console.log(result);
                console.log('success!');
            }, function(error){
                // this code is not being exectued even when response status code is different then 200
                // its never executed at all :(
                console.log('error!');
            });
        }
    };


});
```

When I send the request and I receive response code 400/503, I believe that function(error) code should be executed but it's not.

Instead, my code in `$promise.then(function(result)(...)` is executed and I am not able to detect a response HTTP status code.

So, my questions:

1. Why isn't my error handling function being executed?
2. How can I detect HTTP response status codes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first `.catch` is **converting** rejections to fulfilled. To prevent conversion, the `.catch` method needs to `throw` the error.

```
   authenticationResponse.$promise.catch(function(error){
        alert('catched error!!!');
        //throw to chain error
        throw error;
    }).then(function(result) {
        // this is always fired, even then response code is 400 or 503 :(
        console.log(result);
        console.log('success!');
        //return to chain data
        return result
    }, function(error){
        // This should be executed when status code is different then 200?
        // its never executed at all :(
        console.log('error!');
        //throw to chain rejection
        throw error;
    });
```

When a function omits a `return` or `throw` statement, it returns `undefined`. The `$q` service creates a derived promise that resolves to `undefined`.

---

### Diagnosing `ngResource` Problems

To diagnose problems with `$resource` methods, add a response interceptor:

```
userDevices: $resource(api_url+'/requestRegistration/userDevices/:action', {}, {
        registerDevice: {
            method: 'POST',
            params: {
               action: ''
            },
            interceptor: {
                response: function (response) {
                    console.log("registerDevice success");
                    console.log(response.status);
                    return response;
                },
                errorResponse: function (errorResponse) {
                    console.log("registerDevice error");
                    console.log(errorResponse.status);
                    throw errorResponse;
                }
            }
        },
        verify: {
            method: 'POST',
```

The other thing to look for is other [$http interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) in the App **converting** responses by omitting a **throw** statement.

Comment: It doesn't matter what I do in my catch function - its not being executed at all. Instead, code in .then function is fired always (so I am not able to detect invalid http response status).

Comment: Indeed, my other http interceptor was the issue! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is a function to capture the response of the HTTP status in Angular. You can look to see how it is done here [stack overflow http response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729556/how-do-i-get-the-http-response-status-code-in-angularjs-1-2)

Comment: If you mean $promise.catch(...)  - it also is not fired :(

Comment: Please do not create an answer that simply points at another answer. When you have sufficient privileges, and you think the question is a duplicate of another, you will be able to flag it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an interceptor.

> Intercept requests before they are handed to the server and responses
>   before they are handed over to the application code that initiated
>   these requests

So,
This will catch all response errors originating from $http which $resource.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
     return {
        'responseError': function(response) {
          if (response.status == 400) {
            // Handle 400 error code
          }
          if (response.status == 503) {
            // Handle 503 error code
          }

          // Rejects the derived promise.
          return $q.reject(response);
        }
      };
    });
```