# Unable to test a rejected promise after migrating to Angular 1.6.3

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angular-promise, angularjs-1.6

I have recently updated my application from Angular 1.5 to 1.6.3 and started getting Jasmine unit test failures (with PhantomJS) around promise based code I have written:

> Possibly unhandled rejection: undefined thrown

Reading around I see that the accepted solution is to chain .then() with .catch() blocks to handle the rejections gracefully.

I have done this for one of my source files that I am testing to prove this gets past the error which it does.

However, it has now uncovered a further issue where an expectation I am testing when a promise rejection is called in my code is no longer passing.

This is the function I am trying to test (after adding the required catch blocks)

```
public deleteSomething = (thing) => {
    return this.UserMessages.buildConfirmDialog().then(() => {
        this.someService.remove(thing)
            .then(() => {
                this.UserMessages.showToast('Something deleted');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                //handle error
            });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        //handle error
    });
}
```

And here is the test:

```
var thing = {foo: 'bar'},
    deferredRemove,
    deferredConfirm,
    //Mock service below injected into controller later on before test are run
    UserMessages = {
        buildConfirmDialog: jasmine.createSpy('buildConfirmDialog').and.callFake(function() {
            deferredConfirm = $q.defer();
            return deferredConfirm.promise.catch(angular.noop);
        })
    };

//Inject and controller setup here...

    describe('When deleting something', function() {
        beforeEach(function() {
            deferredRemove = $q.defer();
            spyOn(someService, 'remove').and.returnValue(deferredRemove.promise.catch(angular.noop));
        });
        describe('and the user confirms the deletion', function() {
            beforeEach(function() {
                ctrl.deleteSomething(thing);
                deferredConfirm.resolve();
                deferredRemove.resolve();
                $rootScope.$apply();
            });
            it('should call remove on someService', function() {
                console.log('someService.remove.calls = ' + someService.remove.calls.count());
                expect(someService.remove).toHaveBeenCalled();
            });
        });
        describe('and the user cancels the deletion', function() {
            beforeEach(function() {
                someService.remove.calls.reset();
                vm.deleteSomething(thing);
                deferredConfirm.reject({});
                $rootScope.$apply();
            });
            it('should not call remove on someService', function() {
                console.log('someService.remove.calls = ' + someService.remove.calls.count());
                expect(someService.remove.calls.count()).toEqual(0);
            });
        });
    });
```

I didnt have the `.catch(angular.noop)` parts in prior to upgrading to 1.6.3 and came across some posts suggesting to do this in order to make the tests happy, which certainly helped for me in getting past the unhandled rejection error in my test run.

The problem I am now facing is that for the reject test spec, there should be no call made to a remove function in my service, and so the number of calls should be zero, but it keeps coming out as 1. I added the line to reset the calls in my test to be sure it wasnt the previous test contributing (I know calls are meant to be reset between tests).

This test was running just fine when I was on 1.5, so this has to be something with the way my code\test is written not playing nicely with changes in 1.6.x

Can someone shed some light on what may be going on here please?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I didnt have the `.catch(angular.noop)` parts in prior to upgrading to 1.6.3 and came across some posts suggesting to do this in order to make the tests happy, which certainly helped for me in getting past the unhandled rejection error in my test run.*

Adding `.catch(angular.noop)` will certainly handle the unhandled rejection.

**It converts the rejected promise to a fulfilled promise!!**

Your test is correctly failing because you broke your code.

For more information, see [Catch method not working with $http get request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42733408/5535245)

---

### Changes to $q for AngularJS V1.6

#### report promises with non rejection callback

> Rejected promises that do not have a callback to handle the rejection report
>       this to `$exceptionHandler` so they can be logged to the console.
>
> BREAKING CHANGE
>
> Unhandled rejected promises will be logged to `$exceptionHandler`.
>
> Tests that depend on specific order or number of messages in `$exceptionHandler`
>       will need to handle rejected promises report.

#### treat thrown errors as regular rejections

> Previously, errors thrown in a promise's `onFulfilled` or `onRejected` handlers were treated in a
>       slightly different manner than regular rejections:
>       They were passed to the `$exceptionHandler()` (in addition to being converted to rejections).
>
> The reasoning for this behavior was that an uncaught error is different than a regular rejection, as
>       it can be caused by a programming error, for example. In practice, this turned out to be confusing
>       or undesirable for users, since neither native promises nor any other popular promise library
>       distinguishes thrown errors from regular rejections.
>       (Note: While this behavior does not go against the [Promises/A+ spec](https://promisesaplus.com/), it is not prescribed either.)
>
> This commit removes the distinction, by skipping the call to `$exceptionHandler()`, thus treating
>       thrown errors as regular rejections.
>
> **Note:**
>       Unless explicitly turned off, possibly unhandled rejections will still be caught and passed to the
>       `$exceptionHandler()`, so errors thrown due to programming errors and not otherwise handled (with a
>       subsequent `onRejected` handler) will not go unnoticed.

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating from V1.5 to V1.6](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrate1.5to1.6-ng-services-$q)

Answer (score 4):

disable **Possibly Unhandled Rejection** by this config and test again.

```
app.config(['$qProvider', function ($qProvider) {
    $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
}]);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have seen this configuration option and have also added to my app config