# how to get Http status code from $resource request

Tags: angularjs, promise, resources

Hello I'm new with AngularJS.I want to get status code from this request. this is my code:

```
angular.module('myApp',['ngResource']);
angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl',function ($scope, UserService) {

 UserService.save({name:'Sahar' , email:'abc.abc@yahoo.com'}).$promise

       .then(function (response) {
        console.log('Error status: ' + response.status);
        return response;
    });

});
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('UserService',function ($resource) {
        return $resource('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/:user',{user:'@user'});
    });
```

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729556/how-do-i-get-the-http-response-status-code-in-angularjs-1-2/29435961#29435961

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use "transformResponse"

```
return $resource('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/:user',user:'@user',{
    query: {
        method: 'GET',
        transformResponse: function (data, headers, status) {
            var ret = {data: data, status: status};
            return ret;
        }}

});
```

You'll get data in {data} key and "Status Code" (Eg 200,500,403) in {status} key